# Solidity return all ERC20 tokens before self destruct within same transaction

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to work on a contract that buys and sells within the same contract and self destructs the contract. This happens all in 1 transaction.
However, when it sells - it doesnt sell all, it sells almost 99%.

[image: left over tokens]

How can I make sure that all tokens are sold or sent back to my contract address before it self destructs?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `balanceOf(address(this))` within your contract to get how many tokens you have left, and then `transfer` this to your own address

```
uint256 remaining = IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this))
transfer(your_address, remaining)
```

Optionally, if you don't care about instantly receiving the tokens you can utilize the `create2` opcode to deploy your contract, selfdestruct and then redeploy at the same address. When you finally want to withdraw these tokens, you can write a function which does the following above for all tokens under the contract address.